# plist wont pull into my NSMutableArray. am i missing something?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

So here's my code. I'm trying to display content from a plist into a table and i keep running into errors. ive been at it all day so i'm probably missing something fairly easy. hope you guys can figure out why when i build, the table is empty.

here is my plist (without headers):

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>word</key>
    <string>AWord1</string>
    <key>definition</key>
    <string>here is a definition</string>
    <key>partOfSpeech</key>
    <string>here is a part of speech</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>word</key>
    <string>Bword1</string>
    <key>definition</key>
    <string>here is a definition</string>
    <key>partOfSpeech</key>
    <string>here is a part of speech</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

*edit: closing tags were missing due to misformatting - fixed*

ok. here is my new code. i NSLog'd and decided to back up to before i went to plist. so, if you could help. how would you suggest i pull this data from plist instead (assuming the data is in the plist)

```
//Initialize the array.
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *countriesToLiveInArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Iceland", @"Greenland", @"Switzerland", @"Norway", @"New Zealand", @"Greece", @"Italy", @"Ireland", nil];
NSDictionary *countriesToLiveInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countriesToLiveInArray forKey:@"Countries"];

NSArray *countriesLivedInArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"India", @"U.S.A", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", @"Test", nil];
NSDictionary *countriesLivedInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countriesLivedInArray forKey:@"Countries"];

[listOfItems addObject:countriesToLiveInDict];
[listOfItems addObject:countriesLivedInDict];

//Initialize the copy array.
copyListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Set the title
self.navigationItem.title = @"Countries";

//Add the search bar
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

searching = NO;
letUserSelectRow = YES;
```

i feel as though i'm still not actually telling it to parse the data from the plist. i've only init'd it. thoughts?

Comment: Did you close the array `</array>`?

Comment: The ending `</array>` XML tag is missing.

Comment: What is the actual problem, what errors do you run in? Did you check in the debugger that all your dictionaries and arrays contain what you expect? - If the table view is empty, the problem might be in the datasource methods (numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForItemAtIndexPath), so you could show that code.

Comment: wow im starting to think this is over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems very incomplete, it doesn't bear much relation to the plist. Here are a few issues

- as noted by H2CO3 and Fogmeister, the plist as you show it is missing a closing `</array>` tag (but lets assume that is a typo in the question)
- you load the entire array into a single entry in a `countriesToLiveIn` dictionary (against the key "definition")
- `countriesToLiveIn` becomes a single object in the array `listOfItems`
- you initialise a `copyOfListItems` array but then don't do anything with it

Then you do not indicate where the table is getting it's date from.

If it is from `copyOfListItems`, well that array is empty .: empty table.

If it is from `listOfItems` you will be parsing the `countriesToLiveIn` dictionary somehow, but you don't show how.

If it is directly from the plist array `countriesToLiveInArray` then that missing `</array>` tag could be a clue. You would also need to be parsing the array's contained dictionaries somehow, and you don't show us that code, there could be something wrong there.

To get further with this I suggest copious use of `NSLog` to find out how far the data gets in to your objects. Perhaps you could expand your question with the results if you are still getting stuck.

**update**

Following your updated code, my first suspicion is that there was a problem with your URL.

in your previous edit this is the suspect line

```
NSMutableArray *wordListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/dictpPlist.plist"]];
```

You need to NSLog right after it:

```
NSLog (@"wordListArray %@", wordListArray);
```

To confirm that you are not picking up the plist here. At least then we isolate the problem to this point in your code.

Then we need to question the URL - is it correct? how did the plist get there? can you verify it independently? Is it a local file URL or a network URL?

If you are accessing a network resource, this is quite likely your problem. The `initWithContentsOfURL` methods should only really be used with local filesystem URLs. See for example

[initwithcontentsofurl methods considered harmful](http://akosma.com/2010/05/28/initwithcontentsofurl-methods-considered-harmful/).

You should be using `NSURLConnection` asynchronously instead. Apple is [a little cagey about this also](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

> *aURL*: The location of a file containing a string representation of an array produced by the `writeToURL:atomically:` method.

Assuming this is your issue, why don't you get it working with a local filesystem plist first.

Write one in code from your `listOfItems` array:

```
- (void) createPlist
{
    NSFileManager* fManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError* error;
    NSURL* docsURL = [fManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
                                          inDomain:NSUserDomainMask 
                                 appropriateForURL:nil 
                                            create:NO 
                                             error:&error];

    NSURL* plistURL = [docsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"testlist.plist"];
    [listOfItems writeToURL:plistURL atomically:YES];
}
```

Read it back in, verify it works, then sort out how to do the same over a network.

Comment: Great response. First off, i just copied a portion of the plist. it does have the closed </array>. 
Secondly, i want to get that data from the plist. yes. i've been successful in grabbing this data from hard coded arrays, but im really struggling with grabbing it from the plist. 
copyOfListItems is for a later table, unused at the moment. Any suggestions? :)

im really just kind of going with the very little knowledge i know, without having to rewrite the whole app.

Comment: @Geoff, i've fixed those tags, it was just a `code` formatting issue. You should at least NSLog `countriesToLiveInArray` to see if it reads in the plist ok, then update your question with the result.

Comment: thank you. just made an edit. im backing up all the way to before i added the plist link. how would you suggest i get it from the plist instead of hardcode?

Comment: @GeoffHill, see my update. I suggest you write out your _working_ `listOfItems` array as a plist and read it back in as a test.

Comment: interesting... i wrote out the plist and im still getting just a blank table. yet, when i hard code them in, it works fine. i must be missing something very simple. 

so to answer your questions, yea - i checked the url, the plist, everything. xml is actually my forte.. (can xml be someone's forte?)

Comment: maybe you can direct me to a good tutorial so i can brush up on what im doing wrong? uitableview with a drill down pulling from a local or URL plist? :D

Answer (score -2):

try below code

```
// Path to the plist (in the application bundle)
     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
    @"dictpPlist" ofType:@"plist"];

// Build the array from the plist  
     NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

// Show the string values  
    for (NSString *str in array2)
      NSLog(@"--%@", str);
```

Comment: Would you care to explain how this answers the question?

Comment: @MartinR can you explain why this doesn't help instead of just being rude. Than maybe he can improve his answer.

Comment: @JohnDude: I think that in most cases it is not helpful to just post some code without any explanation how it differs from the code in the question and what the problem of the OP might have been. - In this particular case:  1) The original code loads a plist from a URL, this code loads a plist from a file. 2) The original plist contains an array of dictionaries, this code assumes an array of strings. - Therefore this seems to me as more or less unrelated code.

Comment: @JohnDude i agree. Im not very well versed in objective-c or xcode, so i really wouldnt know where to put this anyway :P

Comment: @MartinR I agree, but I can see why John said what he has said. You have basically done the same thing. Just said its not helpful. So yeah an explanation of why it isn't helpful helps than they can improve their answer here or on future answers. But yeah totally agree this isn't helpful want so ever. SmartWork could you please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks I didn't mean to sound like an ass but I hate it when people criticize saying its wrong and don't explain why its wrong. Also I hate it when people down vote and don't leave a reason.

Comment: @JohnDude, Popeye: I admit that my first comment was a spontaneous reaction. I do hope that most of my comments are more helpful, and I will bear your feedback in mind.

Comment: @JohnDude you guys are both ok. thanks for the help. im still trying to figure this out. i think i need a few more tutorials before i get this locked down.